# How to set two foreign key for one table and these foreign keys are referencing same primary key in another table?

Tags: database, relational-database

Child table creation is given below.....

```
create table match_detail (
  match_id int primary key auto_increment,
  team1_id int(5),
  team2_id int(5), 
  foreign key (team1_id) references team(team_id),
  foreign key(team2_id) references team(team_id)
);
```

Parent table data is given below....

```
create table team(
  team_id int(5) primary key,
  team_name varchar(20)
);
```

I want to create two foreign keys in child table (team1_id,team2_id) where these two fields are referencing same primary key column in another table (team_id i.e, team table)...

Could u please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You are referencing team(team1_id) for key(team2_id), copy paste issue i guess

Comment: Could u pls help to solve this problem????

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect SQL.

```
create table match_detail (match_id int primary key auto_increment,
team1_id int(5),
team2_id int(5), 
foreign key (team1_id) references team(team_id),
foreign key (team2_id) references team(team_id))
```